# Exclude ids in SQL or in the script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm need to exclude some rows by id from SQL query results, but which way will be better to do this?

Using NOT IN by primary key `id`:

```
SELECT id, key1, key2 FROM my_table WHERE id NOT IN (#EXCLUDE_IDS)
```

Or in the post-processed loop after query in the script:

```
 foreach ($rows as $i => $row) {
    if (isset($exclude[$row['id']])) {
      unset($rows[$i]);
    }
 }

 # or
 for ($i = count($rows) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    if (isset($exclude[$rows[$i]['id']])) {
      unset($rows[$i]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do it in the query. Why fetch data you don't need?

Comment: I think in general you want to do things in SQL if possible, however large `not in` lists can be slow. But in this case probably not slower than processing it in PHP

Comment: How do you identify the IDS that you want to exclude. Tell us that and someone will come up with a SQL Query to match yor needs.

Answer (score 3):

When querying from the database, you want to only get information that you require, which why you have the option of selecting the columns in your select statement with the ability to use the conditions in the where

In this case:
1. If you wish to exclude one specific primary key then

```
SELECT ID, KEY1, KEY2 FROM TABLE WHERE ID != 1
```

2. If it based on multiple ids then

```
SELECT ID, KEY1, KEY2 FROM TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN (ids)
```

3. If you wish the exclude to be based on a separate query, then

```
SELECT ID, KEY1, KEY2 FROM TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN(
    SELECT  ID
    FROM    TABLE2
    WHERE   ID IS NOT NULL )
```

An alternative to the NOT IN is 'NOT EXISTS'

Answer (score 2):

**You should fetch the data which is needed**. So doing it in the query with excluding those `id`s is better option. It also decrease the execution and cost.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use next clouse:

```
SELECT id, key1, key2 FROM my_table WHERE id NOT REGEXP '[regexp]';
```

Where `regexp` describes list of ids you want to exclude.

Comment: Any documentation link to your answer?